# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused when trying to use hdfs

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hdfs

I find a problem when I try to use hadoop hdfs command:

```
root@ec2-35-205-125-85:~# hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal ~/input/ ~/input/
copyFromLocal: Call From ip-172-32-5-110.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.32.5.110 to localhost:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

This problem happen not just for -copyFromLocal but for all command start with `hdfs`, for example -ls, -mkdir.....

Comment: Is your namenode running?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

After the following code the problem solved:

```
bash /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-all.sh
```

And after this code the all subnodes should've run, I check it with `jps`, it show the following:

> 2033 SecondaryNameNode
>   2778 Jps
>   2325 NodeManager
>   2195 ResourceManager
>   1691 NameNode

After that run:

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

And then the warning message has gone.